# Python Path in JSON Default Settings not appearing

Tags: path, python-3.10

In VS Code - why is python.pythonPath not showing in my default settings in JSON?
I am using 3.10.2 version of python.

Also:
python.poetryPath
and
python.pipenvPath

show up in default setting, but python.pythonPath does not?